# Google Sheets Addon or Formula that accomplishes the same thing as the Prevsheet Macro's for Excel

Tags: vba, google-sheets

I want to have a cumulative total running on each sheet (so the current total will be a value on the current sheet summed with the cumulative total from the previous sheet, each sheet representing a day of the month. In Excel this was definable in a Macro similar to this.

```
Function PrevSheet(rg As Range)
 n = Application.Caller.Parent.Index
 If n = 1 Then
 PrevSheet = CVErr(xlErrRef)
 ElseIf TypeName(Sheets(n - 1)) = "Chart" Then
 PrevSheet = CVErr(xlErrNA)
 Else
 PrevSheet = Sheets(n - 1).Range(rg.Address).Value
 End If
 End Function
```

Is there anyway to do this in Google Sheets. It keeps referring back to sheet 1. Thanks

I left an editable link here which is a copy of what I am working on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cx9w9vOJXKj2WqYBoJOuZ7dWqP1VunFYpZbMLjdpkKQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that only using a script. Try this:

```
function PrevSheet(range) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var active = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  for (i in sheets) {
    if (sheets[i].getName() === active) {
      return (sheets[i-1].getRange(range).getValues());
    }
  }
}
```

The only problem is, you will have to push the range as a **String** by surrounding it with quotation marks.

This will give you a range of Data

```
=PrevSheet("D2:D6")
```

This will give you the sum

```
=Sum(PrevSheet("D2:D6"))
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want this to be updated, use this script

```
function PrevSheetName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var active = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  for (i in sheets) {
    if (sheets[i].getName() === active) {
      return (sheets[i-1].getName());
    }
  }
}
```

And get the values like this:

```
=INDIRECT(PrevSheetName()&"!D2")
```

And

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(PrevSheetName()&"!D2:D6"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great Thank You. It has me on the right track. It is working a little weird though. It doesn't update. If I type in 

=Sum(PrevSheet("D2:D6"))

It does the calculation. correctly but if I go back at alter D:6's value it doesn't add it in.

Comment: I Just Figured out what it is doing. It is summing everything from the previous sheet. So I need to pull the info from a Previous Sheet put it into a cell make it invisible and then do a calculation. For Example

Cell A27: =PrevSheet ("D2") 
Cell D6 =SUM (A27:D6)

Comment: Thanks. It is partially working. When I use this it does all the calculations from the sheet before. what I have done is use an empty cell to get D2 Cell F6 =PrevSheet("D2") Cell E6 =SUM (D6+F6)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ey4o1csgAqtQoD-QVDIsBmNHdF_m23FG2UyPLmYvKBc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, you said you wanted something similar to a macro, so I thought you wanted a one time value. You can change this script to push the name of previous sheet, and then get the values via indirect. The name of the previous sheet will not change, but the values will always be updated. Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks so Much I will definitely play around with that. I should have been more clear in my question. Of course it made sense to me :-) This particular one is working using the modifications I did above. Not going to upset the apple cart but will start working on revision 2. I know this is probably a common question and I appreciate the help on it.